# javascript html5 stream player

Tags: javascript, html

I'am looking for some javascript player that could play hds or rtmp stream. Can't find it still.

We have a wowza, that is sending to end users a video stream in rtmp, and it is being played with Flowplayer. Now people want to watch this stream on iPad/Android devices. We have succesfully played it on Android 4.0 tablet because I've installed a flash player there. It plays right in the browser. But I cannot find similiar player for iPad. I heared that it does not exist. So the best solution would be some kind of JavaScript player.

Comment: FYI Adobe has discontinued support for Flash on Android. I don't believe it's even available on the Google Play store any more.

Comment: it is available on their archive page for a while http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to play an RTMP stream on a plain webpage in iOS. HDS appears to be closely tied to Flash Player, so you might not be able to use it either, but given that it has HTTP in its name, it might be usable.

If you have some video that you stream the normal way, just use the `video` tag:

```
<video width="800" height="600" src="some-video.mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video. Sorry.
</video>
```

If your video is available in multiple formats, you can drop the `src` attribute on the `video` element and instead have multiple `source` elements with `src` and `type` attributes.

If your web server is configured correctly, video can be streamed this way.

Comment: I cannot prepare it before I put it on the page. It is a live stream.

Comment: Can you, please, explain your idea more particulary? Maybe there are some example links?

Comment: @user2426923: HTTP can stream files to the client. Most video formats have the ability to play the video without it having completely downloaded. You can do a live stream by streaming the video to the client as it is generated. Livestream's mobile site used to do this, but I'm not sure it exists any more. (when I go to their site with a mobile User-Agent, I get their normal site. That used to not be the case.)